# ng build ang-lib doesn't create a assets folder, also doesn't compile Scss files

Tags: angular, build

I have an Angular Library which has an assets folder with Image folder, CSS folder, Scss Folder and Fonts Folder, After building the library the build doesn't have a Assets folder....
If I add an assets option to the library in angular.json I get an error saying

```
Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(assets).
```

Apart from using Gulp to transfer the folder to the build, is there a way to go ?

Comment: in environment.ts add key `assets_endpoint: './assets/'` to fix asset thing

Comment: export const environment = {
  production: false,
  localData: false,
  version: '***name***-1.0.0.1',
  deployURL: null,
  apiURL: 'api/',
  apiUIPath: 'ui/',
  apiAHPath: 'ah/',
  assets_endpoint: './assets/'
};

Comment: if this is what you mean it didn't work